# Parsing JSONArray

Tags: java, json

Parsing JSONArray

```
{
    "SyncUserGpsDataList" :
     [
        {
            "date_time": "2013-03-23 16:34:53PLUS0530",
            "Battery": {
                "Level": "51",
                "State": "Not charging",
                "Temperature": "3.78",
                "Voltage": "30.6",
                "Health": "Good"
            },
            "Location": {},
            "GPS_bool": "true",
            "WIFI_bool": "true",
            "notes": "Trying to get location information"
        }
    ]
}
```

How to parse this JSONArray?

Answer (score 2):

Use a JSON parsing library, like [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

No need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

[Json.org](http://www.json.org/) has a good explanation and tutorial for understanding JSON, as well as a list of libraries across various languages.

It's worth looking into and picking one that suits your needs best.  It's a unclear from your question what you've tried or how you plan to use it, so perhaps some further research is needed.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of libraries that make it fairly painless. I recently used json.jar and you can download it from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/json-lib/files/). The Java docs are posted on [json.org](http://www.json.org/java/index.html)

Here is a little code to get you started:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File json = new File("json.txt"); //stores your sample data.
    Scanner in = new Scanner(json);
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(in.nextLine());
    JSONArray list = obj.getJSONArray("SyncUserGpsDataList");
    System.out.print("Number of elements in this array: ");
    System.out.println(list.length());
    JSONObject data = list.getJSONObject(0);
    System.out.println("Need to parse:" + data.toString());
    System.out.println("\n Keys : Values");
    Iterator itr =data.keys(); 
    //List key-value pairs stored in the JSON object.
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
       String key = itr.next().toString();
       System.out.print(key + "  :  ");
       System.out.println(data.get(key));
    } 
}
```